# Save JSON data in XML file using angular 2 and TypeScript (on HTML 5 application)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have Angular 2 (TypeScript) with HTML5 application.
I want to save REST service response (JSON format) in a XML file.
I have used FileSaver to save file. It is working with text file but does not save in XML format.
I want to convert JSON data in XML and then save into file.
Can any one please help me to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install xml2json --save
```

then

```
var parser = require('xml2json');

var xml = "<foo attr=\"value\">bar</foo>";
console.log("input -> %s", xml)

// xml to json 
var json = parser.toJson(xml);
console.log("to json -> %s", json);

// json to xml 
var xml = parser.toXml(json);
console.log("back to xml -> %s", xml)
```

Comment: I m getting error while installing xml2json as: if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\kl358d\.npmrepo\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error

Comment: how i can use xml2json in angular2/angular4 ? How i can import in my component ?